# Using partykit to predict survival probabilities

Tags: r, machine-learning, party

I am trying to use the MOB procedure from the R package `partykit` to predict survival probabilities based on a set of covariates X1,...,X25 and a treatment effect W. The linear predictor in each node in MOB only uses W, X1, and X2, but each covariate is used for selection for node splitting. I would like to force the MOB to only split according to parameter instability for the treatment effect W. When doing prediction in the final line of code below, I get the following error:

```
Error in rval[ix[[i]], ] <- preds[[i]] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
In addition: Warning messages:
1: 'newdata' had 1070 rows but variables found have 1029 rows 
2: 'newdata' had 1337 rows but variables found have 1291 rows 
3: 'newdata' had 1690 rows but variables found have 1680 rows 
4: 'newdata' had 903 rows but variables found have 1000 rows
```

I believe this error occurs because the number of test observations falling in each terminal node is different than that of the training observations. How can I modify the predict statement to handle this issue and obtain predictions on the test set? I would also like to know if I'm using the `parm` option correctly in specifying that parameter instability should be assessed according to W.

```
library("survival")
library("partykit")

n=5000;n.test=5000;p=25;pi=0.5;beta=1
gamma=0.5;rho=2;cen.scale=4;n.mc=10000;
Y.max=2

generate_data <- function(n, p, pi = 0.5, beta = 1, gamma = 1, rho = 2, cen.scale = 4,
                          Y.max = NULL){
  W <- rbinom(n, 1, pi)
  X <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), n, p)
  numerator <- -log(runif(n))
  cox.ft <- (numerator / exp(beta * X[ ,1] + (-0.5 - gamma * X[ ,2]) * W))^2
  failure.time <- pmin(cox.ft, Y.max)
  numeratorC <- -log(runif(n))
  censor.time <- (numeratorC / (cen.scale ^ rho)) ^ (1 / rho)
  Y <- pmin(failure.time, censor.time)
  D <- as.integer(failure.time <= censor.time)
  list(X = X, Y = Y, W = W, D = D)
}

data <- generate_data(n, p=p, pi = pi, beta = beta, gamma = gamma, rho = rho, cen.scale = cen.scale,
                      Y.max = Y.max)

data.test <- generate_data(n.test, p=p, pi = pi, beta = beta, gamma = gamma, rho = rho, cen.scale = cen.scale,
                      Y.max = Y.max)

X=data$X
Y=data$Y
W=data$W
D=data$D

var_prog <- c("X1","X2")
colnames(X) <- paste("X", 1:25, sep="")
cov.names <- colnames(X)

wbreg <- function(y, x, start = NULL, weights = NULL, offset = NULL, ...) {
  survreg(y ~ 0 + x, weights = weights, dist = "weibull", ...)
}

dat <- data.frame(Y=Y,D=D,W=W,X)

eqn <- paste0("Surv(Y, D) ~ W + ",paste0(var_prog, collapse = "+")," | ",
              paste0(cov.names, collapse = "+"))

glmtr <- partykit::mob(as.formula(eqn), data = dat,
                       fit = wbreg, control = mob_control(parm=2,minsize = 0.2*nrow(dat), 
                                                          alpha = 0.10, bonferroni = TRUE))

plot(glmtr)

dat.test <- data.frame(Y=data.test$Y,D=data.test$D, W=data.test$W,data.test$X)
pct <- 1:98/100
quantile_pred <- predict(glmtr, newdata = dat.test, type = "quantile",p=pct)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `dat.test` only provides the original variables that `mob()` has seen (i.e., `Y`, `D`, `W`, etc.) while `survreg()` has seen the processed variables `y` and `x`.

The `predict()` method for `mob()` trees internally first predicts the node ID (which works smoothly in your example) and then passes on the correct subsets of `newdata` to the `predict()` method for the fitted model objects (from `survreg()` in this case). As the latter does not find the variables `y` and `x` in `newdata` it takes them from the learning data. Hence you get the warnings/errors about the mismatching dimensions.

So there are two ways to deal with this:

1. Make the `survreg` output believe it was fitted with the formula `Surv(Y, D) ~ W + X1 + X2` or
2. modify `newdata` to provide `x`.

Strategy 1 is what `lmtree()` and `glmtree()` do internally. You have to be careful, though, that everything still works correctly when changing the supposed formula and terms. Hence, it is easier to apply strategy 2 safely, which is what I would recommend here.

```
dat.test$x <- model.matrix(~ W + X1 + X2, data = dat.test)
predict(glmtr, newdata = head(dat.test, 4), type = "quantile", p = 1:9/10)
##           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
## 1 0.0044903736 0.019754829 0.049863880 0.10133392 0.18511217 0.32115772
## 2 0.0008963665 0.003943451 0.009953807 0.02022824 0.03695202 0.06410937
## 3 0.0076736262 0.034940287 0.090110107 0.18616205 0.34486226 0.60601526
## 4 0.0014907219 0.006787697 0.017505298 0.03616489 0.06699489 0.11772795
##        [,7]      [,8]      [,9]
## 1 0.5505803 0.9765134 1.9803484
## 2 0.1099066 0.1949312 0.3953163
## 3 1.0520106 1.8908381 3.8980339
## 4 0.2043695 0.3673249 0.7572541
```

*Caveat:* The `predict()` method for `survreg()` objects with a multivariate `p` only returns a matrix if `newdata` has more than one row. If `newdata` has just a single row it returns a vector. This confuses the `predict()` method for `mob()` if it happens in the first node where `predict()` is applied because this determines the dimension of the output object. If it happens in subsequent nodes it is no problem. Also, univariate `p` is never a problem.

*Bonus:* Yes, you are using `parm` as intended. However, note that this only affects the parameter instability tests. Thus, the splitting variables in the tree are selected based on how much the `W` effect changes along those variables. But for selecting the split point in the variable the full log-likelihood of the model (including all regressors) is maximized. Thus, the split point may be sensitive to changes in all coefficients, not just the one of `W`.